# Is there a database for empirical/statistical probabilities?

Tags: data-request

I am trying to explain some estimates of mine to non-academics. So I have statements like "The probability of event X happening is 75%".

If they don't understand probabilities, then I would like to use examples/analogies to convey the meaning. For example, "the probability of event X happening is 75%, which is as likely as the home football team winning the match".

So is there a database where I can search for examples of events, where I enter a probability - say 80% - and it gives me events that occur with 80% probability? Or any website that does this?

I imagine insurance companies have something like this but hopefully you know of something freely available.. Thanks.

Comment: I worked for an insurance company for a long time.  We didn't have a thing like this, but it would have been useful!

Comment: https://www.thedailybeast.com/recy-taylors-baby-brother-decades-before-metoo-she-was-a-fighter has a list of rare probabilities, but that's probably not what you're looking for. You can always say things like "hitting the right number on roulette" or "flipping a coin heads 2 times in a row" or something. Be careful about sayings things like "the Isotopes will win tomorrow", because probabilities like that are based on assumptions and aren't really statistically sound. If you see odds on something you can say "gamblers feel the probability is..."